# Черный экран в Xubuntu после установки драйверов Nvidia

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер, xubuntu, nvidia

После установки драйверов Nvidia, после перезагрузки не появляется изображение. При этом в терминал зайти могу. Но при установке драйверов не в Xubuntu, а в Ubuntu все ставиться без проблем. В чем может быть причина? 
Ноут: Lenovo g50-30
Видео: Intel и Nvidia GeForce 820m
Версии дистрибутивов: 20.04

Comment: А как именно ты ставил драйвер?

Comment: Каким образом организовано переключение между видеокартами? Пробовали ставить [Bumblebee](https://bumblebee-project.org/index.html) или что-то подобное?

Comment: Ставил через gui, шмеля не ставил, так как мне кажется, надо сначала с драйверами разобраться

Comment: @Вадим ну так у вас проблема в этом конфликте может быть. Чтобы была картинка, в общем случае установки драйверов недостаточно. У меня тоже 2 видеокарты. На Xubuntu не пробовал настраивать, но на голую систему (без WM) для появления картинки как минимум надо было поставить и настроить: пакеты иксов, OpenGL реализацию (mesa), nvidia драйвер (nvidia/nouveau), драйвер для дискретной видеокарты (intel xorg), bumblebee/nvidia-xrun/nvidia-prime и т.п. для переключения между картами

Comment: @вася, а можете команды для установки привести?

Comment: @Вадим читайте документацию для вашего дистрибутива. [Пример](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus).